# Accessing Perl Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, mason

I have an array of unknown size in perl generated by some other perl module. Now, precisely I want to find if a value passed to a jquery function exists in the perl array or not.

Is there a way I can do an **element by element** comparison of the input value against each value in perl array?

I looked around and looks like I can access perl array in jquery by providing the index but we don't know the size of the array. So I don't know when to stop.

My mason code looks something similar to:

```
<%perl>
    my @testArray = [call to some other perl module to get the values]
</%perl>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkIfValExistsInTestArray(val) {
        // Code to test if "val" exists in "@testArray". Returns boolean true/false.
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: since they both run in different environments and at different times you need to be far more specific

Comment: @charlietfl I edited the statement and added the sample scenario how my code looks like. I'm fairly new to this technology hence half cooked queries.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I followed following example: http://forums.devshed.com/perl-programming-6/help-accessing-perl-array-javascript-158070.html but since this wouldn't work for unknown size array, I was lost. Remaining all what I tried before reaching this approach doesn't suit this context hence not describing.

Comment: unless you plan to output the whole array as javascript variable you could make ajax call to validate the variable

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. But I gave try to the accepted answer as it clearly described what I've got to do and also I could understand it better with the explanation provided. However, your suggestion could be valuable to somebody who has better idea of how ajax call is done. Hence, upvoting. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for existence, you'd want a hash. A simple way of transmitting the data would be to encode it using [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON).

```
% use JSON qw( );

<script type="text/javascript">

var testArray = <% JSON->new()->encode({ map { $_ => 1 } get_values() }) %>;

function checkIfValExistsInTestArray(val) {
   return testArray[val];
}

</script>
```

For example, if `get_values()` returned `apple` and `orange`, you'd get

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var testArray = {"apple":1,"orange":1};

function checkIfValExistsInTestArray(val) {
   return testArray[val];
}

</script>
```

I don't know Mason, so there could be errors, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Thanks a ton. Looking at your edited version it makes clear to me what we are trying to do here. You are serializing the perl versioned list of array to JSON map with values having 1 and trying to lookup into the map. I have no idea of the JSON modules being used but this is what I could pull out from your code. Please correct me if 'm wrong.

Comment: That's right. JSON is a subset of JS, so you are basically generating JS code to create an Object you can query.